# How to add classNames in conditional rendering in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I have a list of data with images. I want to make image carousel. For this I have created card component and I want here to display 4 cards at a time and remaining should be hidden.  Then i want to `setTimeout` of `5s` to display remaining but only for at a time.
So far I have done this.

> about.js

```
import './about.scss';
import data from '../../data/data';
import CardSection from './card';


class About extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            properties: data.properties,
            property: data.properties[0]
        }
    }

    nextProperty = () => {
    const newIndex = this.state.property.index+4;
    this.setState({
      property: data.properties[newIndex]
    })
  }

  prevProperty = () => {
    const newIndex = this.state.property.index-4;
    this.setState({
      property: data.properties[newIndex]
    })
  }

    render() {
        const {property, properties} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="section about__wrapper">
            <div>
            <button 
            onClick={() => this.nextProperty()} 
            disabled={property.index === data.properties.length-1}
            >Next</button>
            <button 
            onClick={() => this.prevProperty()} 
             disabled={property.index === 0}
            >Prev</button>
            <Container className="card__container">    
            <div class="card__main" style={{
                'transform': `translateX(-${property.index*(100/properties.length)}%)`
            }}>
                {
                    this.state.properties.map(property => (
                        <CardSection property={property}/>
                    ))
                }
            </div>
            </Container>    
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
export default About
```

> about.scss

```
.card__container{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .card__main{
        display: flex;
        position: absolute;
        transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
        .card__wrapper {
            padding: 20px;
            flex: 1;
            min-width: 300px;
        }
    }
```

> card.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
  CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button } from 'reactstrap';
class CardSection extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card__wrapper">
      <Card>
                <CardImg top width="100%" src={this.props.property.picture} alt="Card image cap" />
        <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>{this.props.property.city}</CardTitle>
                    <CardSubtitle>{this.props.property.address}</CardSubtitle>
          <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
          <Button>Button</Button>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CardSection;
```

I have added transition in them to change card onclick but i want them to auto change and hide the remaining card.

Right now it looks like this,

[image: error]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i make only 4 cards display at a time and remaining should be hidden. and after 3s  I want to display next 4 card. like a gallery.

Answer (score 1):

You can add items in componentDidMount method using setInterval

```
    componentDidMount() {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({
                                         properties:data.properties /* add your data*/ }), 4000);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a property called `showCardIds` that holds an array of the Id of cards that need to be shown, and use that to set a Boolean property called `hidden` on the div of the card.

You could also do something like this as shown in the example below, this example also uses `showCardIds` as a state. It filters only for the `property` that needs to be rendered and filters out the rest.
Here is an example:

```
...
                {
                    this.state.properties.filter((property, index) => showCardIds.includes(index)).map(property => (
                        <CardSection property={property}/>
                    ))
                }
...
```

That way only the ones that are present in the array of `showCardIds` would show up, there needs to be more logic to be written that would populate the ids in `showCardIds`

Hope this helps. The `hidden` property is supported from HTML5, and should work on most browsers, unless they are truly "ancient".

Comment: But i don't want all of them to be hidden i want only.

Comment: Check out a code example, that might help you understand better.